# Как в Java отсортировать массив по булеановому значению параметра элементов?

Tags: java, сортировка

В данной проге реализована сортировка (`Sort`) по возрастанию значения номера зачётки. Мне нужно изменить эту сортировку на сортировку по значению `true/false` `Army` в `Student` (типа, сначала все элементы со значением `1`, потом `0`). Не понимаю как это сделать.
Помогите пж

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Student _1 = new Student("Michail", "Gorshenev", true, 12323);
        Student _2 = new Student("Andrew", "Knyazev", false, 22122);
        Student _3 = new Student("Alexandr", "Schigolev", true, 56783);
        Student _4 = new Student("Viktor", "Tsoy", true, 102221);
        Student _5 = new Student("Till", "Lindeman", true, 78890);

        Student[] Array = {_1, _2, _3, _4, _5};
        Array = Sort(Array);
        Output(Array);
        System.out.println("Результат пошуку:\n");
        Student SearchResult = interpolationSearch(Array, 78890);
        if (SearchResult != null) {
            SearchResult.Output();
        } else {
            System.out.println("No Student found!");
        }
    }

    public static Student[] Sort(Student[] Array) {
        boolean IsSorted = false;
        while(!IsSorted) {
            IsSorted = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < Array.length - 1; i++) {
                if (Array[i].ID > Array[i + 1].ID) {
                    IsSorted = false;
                    Student Temp = Array[i];
                    Array[i] = Array[i + 1];
                    Array[i + 1] = Temp;
                }
            }
        }
        return Array;
    }

    public static void Output(Student[] Array) {
        for(Student student : Array) {
            student.Output();
        }
    }

    public static Student interpolationSearch(Student[] Array, int value) {
        int mid;
        int start = 0;
        int end = Array.length - 1;

        while (Array[start].ID < value && Array[end].ID > value) {
            mid = start + ((value - Array[start].ID) * (end - start)) / (Array[end].ID - Array[start].ID);

            if (Array[mid].ID < value)
                start = mid + 1;
            else if (Array[mid].ID > value)
                end = mid - 1;
            else if(Array[mid].Army)
                return Array[mid];
        }

        if (Array[start].ID == value && Array[start].Army)
            return Array[start];
        if (Array[end].ID == value && Array[start].Army)
            return Array[end];

        return null;
    }
}

class Student {
    String Name;
    String Surname;
    boolean Army;
    int ID;

    public Student(String name, String surname, boolean army, int gradebook_ID ) {
        Name = name;
        Surname = surname;
        ID = gradebook_ID;
        Army = army;
    }

    public void Output() {
        System.out.println(Surname + " " + Name  + "\nВійськова підготовка: " + Army + "\nНомер залікової книжки: " + ID + "\n");
    }
}
```

(извините за лишний код, не бейте)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала давайте добавим в ваш класс **Student** геттер для поля **Army** *(потому как по хорошему поля в классе должны быть недоступны за пределами класса)*:

```
class Student {
    //...
    private boolean Army;
    //...

    public boolean isArmy() {
        return Army;
    }

    //...
}
```

Теперь о сортировке, если хотите, вот подправленный вариант с вашей сортировкой:

```
public static Student[] Sort(Student[] Array) {
    boolean IsSorted = false;
    while(!IsSorted) {
        IsSorted = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < Array.length - 1; i++) {
            if (!Array[i].isArmy() && Array[i + 1].isArmy()) {
                IsSorted = false;
                Student Temp = Array[i];
                Array[i] = Array[i + 1];
                Array[i + 1] = Temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return Array;
}
```

- *Если i-тый элемент имеет Army == false, а (i+1)-ый Army == true, то они поменяются местами и сортировка продолжится.*

Вместо данного метода можно использовать потоки прямо из **main**:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

//...

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //...

    Student[] Array = {_1, _2, _3, _4, _5};
    Student[] Sorted1 = Arrays.stream(Array)
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Student::isArmy).reversed())
                .toArray(Student[]::new);

    //...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант

В классе Student надо геттер для поля Army

```java
class Student {
//...
    
    public boolean getArmy() {
        return Army;
    }

//...
}
```

И сделать сортировку через `Arrays.sort()`

У твоем случае метод `Sort()` будет выглядеть следующим образом

```java
    public static void Sort(Student[] Array) {
        Arrays.sort(Array, Comparator.comparing(Student::getArmy).reversed());
    }
```

ну и надо `Array = Sort(Array);` поменять на `Sort(Array);`